# React.js Scroll to top after rendering Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem.

I am fetching different data from the backend, which takes different amount of time. So some components are already rendered and others are still waiting for data. Now it is that I am displaying a loading circle while the data is being loaded. Once the component has finished rendering, I am taken to the top of the page. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you add the code for your frontend where you're facing this problem for better context

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because it's internal code.

Comment: I think you are conditionally rendering the components. While the data is being loaded you conditionally render Loader and once data comes you change the state and renders the component. Maybe this is the reason. Try using an overlay or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overlay. Do you have an example? The only thing I've found is something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

But this is unfortunately not usable, because the other components should be useable in the meantime anyway.